# Android Studio EditText center hint and left-align input text

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, alignment

I was wondering if it is possible in an `EditText` field to make the `android:hint` attribute centered, while the text the user types in would get left-aligned in the `EditText`.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Not built in.  You could try putting a text watcher on it and changing the alignement based on whether the text is empty or not.  If that doesn't work, you could overlay the view with a textview, use the textview for the hint, and just no use the edit text's hint functionality.  The first of those would be much easier.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks, I did it now with a Textwatcher and changed the android:gravity attribute depending on my defined bool.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this in Android by using a combination of **android:gravity** and **android:padding** attributes. You can set the android:gravity attribute to center for the hint in the EditText to center it, and then set the android:gravity attribute to left for the input text to make it left-aligned. Additionally, you may need to adjust the **android:padding** attribute to ensure proper spacing.

Here's an example:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" <!-- Center the hint -->
    android:paddingStart="8dp" <!-- Adjust padding as needed -->
    android:paddingEnd="8dp" <!-- Adjust padding as needed -->
    android:hint="Enter text"
   />
```

*This might help you if want to do this with edit text in xml.*